# Google Cloud API Gateway - Security Features

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, gateway

I looked through all the documents of the API Gateway but was not able to find any reference of the security features that Google API Gateway provides - for example does it provide any protection from DDOS attacks, or OWASP security features. Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got confused between API Gateway and Cloud Armor.

Cloud Armor is the one that protects you from DDOS attacks. You can also find the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor).

Comment: I think he wanted to know how API gateway in GCP can be protected with service like Armor?  Does armor support API gateway integration ( I guess no).  IF you look at AWS, the WAF, Shield can be integrated with AWS API gateway.